# Find multiplicative function $f:\Bbb R\to$ $p$th roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers, functional-equations, roots-of-unity

> For prime number $p$, find all functions $f:\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\to\left\{\mathrm e^{\frac{2k\pi\mathrm i}p}\mid k\in\Bbb Z_+\right\}$ such that $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ for all real numbers $a$, $b$.

This problem is very hard, even for small $p$. I tried $f(a)=f(1)f(a)$, so $f(1)=1$. Therefore,
$$f(a)f\left(\frac1a\right)=f(1)=1,~\forall a\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}.$$
I can't derive anything more.

Comment: Consider the possible values of $f(a)$ if $a$ has a $p$th root in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hint: we're asked to find the group homomorphisms from $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\} \cong \Bbb R^+ \times \{\pm1\}$ into a cyclic group of order $p$. Note that $\Bbb R^+$ is torsion-free and finite groups are torsion; that doesn't leave many options....

Comment: @GregMartin I'm afraid I only know propaedeutic knowledge of group theory. Is there any way to explain it more elementarily?

Comment: As @anomaly commented: given any $a\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, consider the relationship between $f(a^{1/p})$ and $f(a)$.